# A simple Parameterized Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need a very simple stored procedure, suppose we have some data of employees in a table. One of column contain `NickName` of employees. `NickName` column is a nullable, for example we have 10 records and 7 employees have nick name whereas other 3 are null. I want to pass a parameter for `NickName`; if I pass value in parameter, data should be returned according to parameter value and if don’t pass any value in parameter then all 10 records should be displayed means both `NickName` and null value records should be displayed.

The following stored procedure is functioning well but it doesn't return the rows with NULL values:

```
    @name VARCHAR(30) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM Emp 
    WHERE NickName = ISNULL(@name, NickName)
END
```

I will be very thankful if some answered, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like following

```
@name varchar(30)= NULL
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * from Emp where ISNULL(NickName,'') = COALESCE(@name,Nickname, '')
end
```

Comment: works excellent, unfortunately I have no reputation to award you

Answer (score 2):

```
@name varchar(30)= NULL
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * from Emp where NickName IS NULL OR NickName  = @name
end
```

Comment: I check it, it dont returned the null values